# What is the difference between calling Dispose or setting to "default" in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, dispose

I've inherited code which sets view elements to default in OnDestroy() rather than call Dispose() in all Fragments.  What is the difference between/impact of these approaches?

e.g.

```
    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        ClearViewElements();

        base.OnDestroy();
    }

    private void ClearViewElements()
    {
        _aRecyclerView.RemoveAllViewsInLayout();
        _aRecyclerView.SetAdapter(null);
        if (_aListAdapter != null)
        {
            _aListAdapter.DeleteClick = default;
            _aListAdapter = default;
        }
        _aRecyclerView = default;
        _aButton = default;
        _anEditText = default;
        _aLayout = default;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `default` will just set the value to the object default, which should be `null`.

Assuming it is `null`, this has similarities with `Dispose`, but it is not the same. As the object shouldn't have any reference any more (with some caveats like if all subscriptions are cleared) it is available for the garbage collection and it should be eventually collected. However with `Dispose` you mark that the object should be collected, so the app is aware of that from that moment, not from the moment when it checks for the free references.

Comment: Would you say dispose is preferable to setting to null/default?

Comment: @IntoTheBlue yes